# Custom error message for type mismatch binding errors

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Consider following method:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/foo", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public void doIt(@Valid PojoRequest request, BindingResult result) throw Exception
{
    if(result.hasErrors())
    {
        throw new Exception(result.getFieldError().getDefaultMessage());
    }
}

class PojoRequest {
    String int id;
    //getter
}
```

When I test this method properly with a `String` parameter, I get the following error:

> Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'int' for property 'id'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "abc"

I can find this data from `BindingResult`, but what I want to do is add an annotation to the field itself and write the error message into the annotation. Is this possible?

Comment: Why are you letting the client set a database key?

Comment: This is just a dummy code. Although the original code is something similar to this, there is no database operation anywhere near this code part. I don't know why you just said that. @NeilMcGuigan

Comment: So you just want to change the error message...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved in one way, I'd appreciate the others.

This is not a readable answer, this is actually a hack, **please use with extreme precautions.**

I defined a custom annotation with a custom validator:

```
@Documented
@Target({ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.PARAMETER, ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = ValidIntegerValidator.class)
public @interface ValidInteger {
    String message() default "not a valid integer!";
    int min() default 1;
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}

public class ValidIntegerValidator implements ConstraintValidator<ValidInteger, Object> {
    @Override
    public void initialize(ValidInteger constraintAnnotation) {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(Object value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        try {
            Integer.parseInt((String) value);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Then, I changed the pojo field as follows:

```
class PojoRequest {
    @ValidInteger(message = "id is faulty")
    private Object id;
    public int getId() {
        return (int) id;
    }

    public void setStartHour(Object id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

Setter is not necessary, but if you define one you should take `Object` as parameter.

This fulfills my needs and also it's extremely ugly. Prettier solutions are appreciated.